# Codeigniter Form post controller advice

Tags: php, codeigniter

would like some advice/help on how to connect form controller to post form method in my CI site. I want to data submitted from one viewer to another. Thank you for the help!!

Here is the controller Im using (Form.php), took if from another site:
Form.php

```
<?php
class Form extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}

// Show form in view page i.e view_page.php
public function form_show() {
$this->load->view("addEdit");
}

// When user submit data on view page, Then this function store data in array.
public function data_submitted() {
$data = array(
'file_name' => $this->input->post('file'),
'title' => $this->input->post('title')
);

// Show submitted data on view page again.
$this->load->view("profile", $data);
}
}
?>
```

Its to connect to this code:
addEdit.php

```
<form method="post" action="postAction.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Image</label>
                    <?php if(!empty($imgData['file_name'])){ ?>
                        <img src="uploads/images/<?php echo $imgData['file_name']; ?>">
                    <?php } ?>
                    <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter title" value="<?php echo !empty($imgData['title'])?$imgData['title']:''; ?>" >
                </div>
                <a href="profile.php" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo !empty($imgData['id'])?$imgData['id']:''; ?>">
                <input type="submit" name="imgSubmit" class="btn btn-success" value="SUBMIT">
            </form>
```

When I first tried to make it work I got this error:

404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

http://culturedkink.com/index.php/register/postAction.php(the url)

postAction.php is the form Im trying to get the data to work from

The end result is to have info submitted from addEdit.php be seen on profile.php with the help of postAction.php

Comment: if i remember correctly, codeigniter just follow the route based on the method name you declare in your controller, so naturally. `postAction` is undefined in your controller, thus the 404. just declare another method in your controller to process the form submission

Comment: isn't it `base url/controller name/method name`, isn't this codeigniter's principle?

Comment: I believe so. The situation is Im using pure php and trying to convert. I got the code from a website but the person who created the code doesn't seem to want to help unless I pay them to implement. I want to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

make routes for it first.

config/routes.php

```
$route['add'] = 'Controller_name/data_submitted';
$route['edit/(:any)'] = 'Controller_name/data_submitted/$1';
```

**where is your add/edit button put this there 
for add**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('/add'); ?>" class="btn btn-success"> Add New</a>
```

**for edit button
$row['id'] is an example i m giving. you can get data by name and id..whatever you want.**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('/edit/' . $row['id']); ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Update</a>
```

//controller

```
public function data_submitted($id=0) {
$data=array();
$data['dataDetails']=$this->get_profile_data_by_id($id);
$data['view'] = 'folder_name/addEdit';
if ($id > 0) {
$profileArray = [
'file_name' => $this->input->post('file'),
'title' => $this->input->post('title')
];
if ($this->User_model->editById($id, $profileArray)) {
$id = $id;
}
}
else{
$profileArray = [
'file_name' => $this->input->post('file'),
'title' => $this->input->post('title')
];
if ($this->User_model->add($id, $profileArray)) {
$id = $id;
}
}
$this->load->view("profile", $data);
}
```

**form view page**

```
 <?php echo isset($dataDetails) ? "Update" : "Add"; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the info, this means alot!!

Answer (score 0):

First check your form method and action. Your action does not exist.  First check how CI works with form. The action should have a method declared in a controller. The url looks like this, 
When you submit the form the data will be submitted in this method. Whatever you need to do with this form data you can do that in this method.

Comment: Cool, will do!!